how to write a extracted value from truclient script to any external file
I am using load runner latest version from opentext. Scripts are created in truclient protocol as per requirements.In the current script a quote number is generated which is dynamic and it will be used as input to other scripts. so the value should be correlated and exported to external file.Correlation is working fine and assigned to a variable(QNum) in the get property step but not sure how to write the extracted values to external file.
I tried adding evaluate javascript code TC.log(QNum). This step displays the correlated value in replay log. But for execution i need to write these values to csv file. how to do that?
